# How can I write-protect a DVD or CD?

Tags: dvd, compact-disc, burning, write-protect

I would like to burn a write-protected DVD.

It contains video in MP4 format.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: To whomever gave this a -1. This is a valid question, even if it is that simple. Giving it a +1 for that reason.

Comment: @LPChip The question shows absolutely zero research effort – a valid reason to downvote it.

Answer (score 3):

CDs and DVDs come in two flavors: CD-R, DVD-R and CD-RW, DVD-RW.

The RW means you can keep clearing and writing to them. The R means you can only do this once.

So the simple answer is: just use a CD-R or DVD-R (or DVD+R) and write to it once, then it is read-only by default.

AFH makes a good point: If you make the CD/DVD a data disk that you can write to from your Windows Explorer, then you also need to finalize the disk at the end. If you use a burning program and write it all, by default the checkmark to finalize the disk is already enabled.

Comment: You also need to finalise it during the burn process.